# Que significan los caracteres del tipo "\u0..."

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

Estos caracteres que significan:

```
"\u0001"
"\u0013"
"\u0004"
"\u0003"
"\u0018"
"\u001A"
"\u0016"
"\u0002"
```

Cuando presiono la tecla ctrl me sale estoy usando el IDE de qt y un programa para mostrar teclas. Gracias.

Comment: `\u` es un código de escape para representar caracteres unicode de 4 bits en algunos sistemas, en otras palabras, al escribir una cadena con uno de esos valores estas escribiendo el caracter `0001` de la tabla unicode *(o ascii)*, o eso tengo entendido.

Answer (score 5):

En C++ `\u` ó `\U` indican caracteres unicode.

`\u` para 16 bit.
`\U` para 32 bit.

Los caracteres unicode son un estándar para representar caracteres en diferentes lenguajes o regiones, un carácter puede ser representado de la misma forma en cualquier región o lenguaje, se puede decir que es la representación universal de un carácter.

---

- Como ejemplo la representación de la letra

  [image: **ñ**]

  usada en el idioma español, sería:

`'\u00F1'` o `'\U000000F1'`

- Otro ejemplo el simbolo del Euro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Su representación sería:

sería:

`'\u20AC'` o `'\U000020AC'`

---

Ejemplo de uso:

```
cout << "Deseo imprimir estos caracteres: \u00F1 y \u20AC" << endl;
```

Salida:

```
Deseo imprimir estos caracteres: ñ y €
```

---

Aquí se tiene una tabla en la cual se representan todos los caracteres:

http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character

Comment: si quiero cambiar los unicode a la representación en char como sería es solo esto y ya sería la mejor respuesta disculpa y gracias.

Comment: Por ejemplo char b = '\u20AC'; (16 bits).

Comment: tengo que ponerle siempre el UTF-8 (hex) sino da el siguiente error: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27163/un-nombre-de-caracter-universal-especifica-un-caracter-no-valido-con-qt

Comment: vale lo solucione mil gracias esta perfecto esto!

Comment: Excelente Omar! agrega tu respuesta en  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27163/un-nombre-de-caracter-universal-especifica-un-caracter-no-valido-con-qt SALUDOS!

Answer (score 3):

En uno de tus comentarios pusiste "si quiero cambiar los unicode a la representación en char [...]". Creo que esa pregunta refleja que no tienes claro como funciona las codificaciones de carácteres, y su diferencia cuando dichos carácteres se muestran en una ventana o en una terminal. Así que lo explico *to'* con el objetivo de aclarar cualquier otra duda que salga por el camino.

## ASCII

Empecemos por ASCII. ASCII es una codificación nacida para estandarizar los "carácteres" que se utilizaban en los teletipos (parecidas a máquinas de escribir). Eran un total de 128 carácteres diferentes, numerados del 0 al 127. La mayoría, imprimibles, como `a`, `0`, o `=`. Otros eran caracteres de control, como por ejemplo el retorno de carro (en una máquina de escribir, utilizada para poner el "carro" de la máquina de escribir al principio de la línea), o el salto de línea (para "girar la rueda" y poder escribir en una línea nueva. Otros caracteres especiales de esos 128 eran el salto de página (cambiar de página), fin de encabezado (para protocolos especiales), tabulaciones horizontal y vertical (es decir, indentación), etc, etc.

Se les llaman carácter de control porque, cuando un teletipo recibía dicho carácter, más que "imprimir" algo, más bien provocaba una acción. Es decir, son carácter para controlar el flujo del texto o de la comunicación.

Para guardar esos 128 carácteres solo necesitas 7 bits (matemática simple, 2^7 = 128). Como los procesadores se comportan mejor con 8 bits que con 7, cada código ASCII (el valor numérico correspondiente a cada carácter ASCII), se guarda en una palabra de 1 byte. Como con 8 bits puedes guardar hasta 256 carácteres, pero ASCII solo contempla 128, ¡te sobra la mitad!

## CODE PAGES

¿Qué hacemos con esa otra mitad? Pues meter más carácteres. Así, Windows inventó los *code pages*, que no son más que diferentes codificaciones para reutilizar los otros 128 valores disponibles en un byte. Así, los valores del 128 al 255 se utilizaban para representar diferentes carácteres según fueses griego, español (para los acentos), ruso o hebreo, por ejemplo.

En el caso de los emoticonos, que te los puedes encontrar en la típica terminal MS-DOS al imprimir ciertos textos, no son más que una manera de sustituir carácteres de control en desuso, por carácteres imprimibles, para algunos code pages.

¿Qué implica? Que si tú tienes un editor de textos, que piensa que va a recibir un texto codificado en el code page griego, los valores del 128 al 255 se imprimirán de manera diferente que si piensa que el code page es ruso. Por eso, un mismo texto (conjunto de bytes/carácteres), se va a imprimir de manera diferente en diferentes editores o terminales según la codificación configurada en dicho editor/terminal para interpretar los textos recibidos.

Evidentemente, si yo envío un correo desde mi casa a un ruso, un ruso va a recibir un texto sin sentido, porque va a imprimir mi correo español con carácteres rusos. Sin embargo, los 128 primeros valores (del 0 al 127), es decir, la "parte ASCII", se va a imprimir por igual en cualquier caso, dado que esa primera mitad del conjunto de valores está estandarizado y "no se toca".

## Unicode

Evidentemente, lo de los code pages era algo un poco caótico (aunque no extinto), así que han aparecido muchos estándares para intentar poner algo de órden. Así, hay diferentes estándares como ISO-8859-1, que hace referencia al alfabeto latino (ASCII + vocales acentuadas, eñes, símbolo de copyright etc), ISO-8859-15 (una mutación de 8859-1 con el símbolo del euro, por ejemplo), etc.

La mayoría de 1 byte, es decir, todos con una limitación de 255 carácteres. Hasta que aparece Unicode. Unicode intenta poder representar todos los carácteres del mundo, y es una "codificación de 21 bytes" (cuidado con ésto, lo aclaro luego). Hay símbolos para todos los idiomas del mundo, para lingüistas, símbolos musicales, de meteorología, matemáticas, misceláneos (hasta balones de fútbol o el símbolo del comunismo), en fin, de todo.

## Pregunta original

"si quiero cambiar los unicode a la representación en char [...]"

Un `char` tiene un byte. En un `char` solo puedes guardar carácteres que quepan en un byte. Es decir, cualquier carácter ASCII, o ISO-8859-1 o ISO-8859-15, etc, pero no cualquier carácter unicode. C y C++ también disponen de "carácteres anchos" (`wchar`), que tienen dos bytes cada uno, así que en un `wchar` puedes guardar hasta 65536 carácteres diferentes.

Como podrás comprender, los carácteres unicode pueden necesitar de hasta 3 bytes (aunque la inmesa mayoría de carácteres unicode caben en 2), así que no todo carácter unicode puede guardarse en un `char`. Además, incluso aunque guardes carácteres en `wchar`, eso no implica que, si quieres "mostrarlos por pantalla", se vayan a ver correctamente. Eso depende de la codificación de la terminal o editor de texto donde quieras ver esos carácteres, o de si el editor detecta la codificación de carácteres que utiliza el texto.

Cuando programas, sin embargo, el objeto binario que tienes no es un fichero de texto, es un fichero binario, y por tanto, no tiene codificación de carácteres. Los "valores" que hayas guardado en un `wchar` se guardarán en memoria según su código binario.

Cuando "imprimas" (printf/cout), dicho carácter, la terminal que imprimirá dicho carácter solo va a recibir una secuencia binaria, y no va a saber si ha recibido dos `char`s o un `wchar`, así que no sabrá si interpretar dicha secuencia como dos carácteres ASCII/ISO-8859-* o como un solo carácter de 16 bits en cualquier otra codificación de 16 bits que exista.

Hay un problema para especificar "qué codificación" se está devolviendo, a la hora de decirle a la terminal cómo debe de mostrar las secuencias de texto que reciba, es decir, cómo interpretar (bajo que codificación), la cadena binaria (si en carácteres 1 o 2 bytes, y a qué carácter en particular corresponde cada valor).

## UTF-32 y UTF-16

Unicode, sin embargo, es un estándar, no una implementación. Con eso quiero decir, que Unicode ofrece un mapeo entre carácteres y valores numéricos, no como implementar el "motor que hace la traducción". UTF-8, UTF-16 y UTF-32 son tres de estas codificaciones.

En UTF-32, cada carácter ocupa 4 bytes. Por tanto, todo carácter Unicode puede representarse con UTF-32. Lo que pasa que la mayoría de los carácteres de casi prácticamente cualquier texto en cualquier idioma, solo necesitan como máximo 16 bits. Imagina un inglés que escribe "Hello" en un fichero UTF-32. Como el fichero es UTF-32, guardará cada carácter utilizando 32 bits, por lo que la cadena "Hello" ocupará (5 carácteres) * (4 bytes cada carácter) = 20 bytes, cuando en ISO-8859-1 solo ocupa 5 bytes. Es un desperdicio enorme.

En UTF-16, cada carácter ocupa 2 bytes (16 bits). Si hubiese que representar un carácter que no quepa en 2 bytes, utilizaría 4 bytes para ese carácter. Así que UTF-16 necesita un mecanismo para saber si el siguiente carácter del texto, es de una o de dos palabras. De esta manera, "Hello" ocuparía 10 bytes (la mitad); ahorras mucho espacio, y además, solo en ciertos casos particulares donde necesites enviar un cáracter más "grande", aún así podrás representarlo.

Evidentemente, si yo muestro un texto codificado en UTF-16, en un editor de texto **que lo sabe** (porque se lo indico al editor o lo detecta), él mostrará correctamente cada carácter porque sabrá como funciona la codificación y mirará si cada carácter ocupa 16 o 32 bits antes de renderizarlo.

## UTF-8

UTF-8 es el otro extremo. Utiliza palabras de 1 byte. Si se quiere representar un carácter que no quepa en 1 byte, utilizará dos. Si necesita 3 bytes, pues utilizará 3 bytes. Al igual que UTF-16, tiene un mecanismo para jugar con la cadena binaria de modo que se represente al mismo tiempo el valor Unicode correspondiente al carácter, y si dicho valor unicode se ha guardado en 1, 2 o 3 bytes, etc. Y si el editor de texto sabe que tiene que mostrar un fichero UTF-8, pues aplicará el mismo algoritmo para detectar el tamaño del siguiente carácter a imprimir.

En un texto puramente ASCII, UTF-8 tiene exáctamente el mismo aspecto, dado que los primeros 128 carácteres Unicode son ASCII. Además, no desperdicia memoria. El tema es que, al ser UTF-8 una codificación de tamaño variable (cada carácter puede ocupar 1, 2 o 3 bits), se minimiza el espacio ("hello" ocupará 5 bytes), pero se maximiza su procesamiento, porque a cada carácter se debe de detectar si ocupa 1, 2 o 3 bytes, lo que hace al algoritmo más lento que UTF-16, y aún más que a UTF-32.

## Qt/GUI

Si tu quieres mostrar, en una ventana, un widget o lo que sea, un texto, lo puedes guardar como cadena, "insertando" en la cadena secuencias como `"Hola\u00F1"` para indicar el correspondiente valor Unicode. Lo que hace el compilador es sustituir la aparición de la secuencia `"\u00F1"` por la representación binaria en UTF-8 del carácter Unicode correspondiente al valor `0x00F1`.

Luego, si pasas dicha cadena a `QString::fromUtf8`, dicha función leerá "binariamente" la cadena recibida como si fuera una cadena en UTF-8 (que lo es, dado que el prefijo `"Hola"` es UTF-8, ya que UTF-8 es compatible con ASCII, y el carácter `0x00F1` ha sido substituido por la secuencia UTF-8 correspondiente), y lo guardará a su manera.

Luego, si se pasa ese `WString` con la cadena correctamente guardada a un widget para ser dibujado, `Qt` se encargará de hablar adecuadamente con el "gestor gráfico" de tu sistema para que sea éste quién finalmente imprime la cadena de la manera adecuada. Todo muy adecuado por aquí.

**Nota:** En realidad, un literal de cadena (`"..."`) que contenga carácteres Unicode, puede transformarse en una cadena UTF-8, UTF-16 o cualquier otra. No está estandarizado qué codificación debe utilizarse en esos casos (aunque normalmente será UTF-8). En C++11, sin embargo, añadieron la notación `u8"..."` para indicar que la cadena debe codificarse en UTF-8, `u"..."` para UTF-16, y `U"..."` para UTF-32.

## En definitiva,

comprenderás que no puedes pasar un carácter unicode a un simple `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Son caracteres unicode muy útiles para representar caracteres especiales, te dejo un listado de los que me han ayudado bastante

Á       \u00C1

á       \u00E1

É       \u00C9

é       \u00E9

Í       \u00CD

í       \u00ED

Ó       \u00D3

ó       \u00F3

Ú       \u00DA

ú       \u00FA

Ü       \u00DC

ü       \u00FC

?       \u00D1

ñ       \u00F1

&       \u0022

<       \u003C

í       \u00ED

”       \u0022

‘       \u0027

©       \u00A9

®       \u00AE

€       \u20AC

¼       \u00BC

½       \u00BD

¾       \u00BE

De este modo en tu código puedes reemplazar una á por \u00E1 y evitar que luego este se arruine.

Comment: estuve buscando y no aparecen en las teclas virtuales de windows:

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx asi que son teclas unicode ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Se llaman caracteres Unicode. Sirven para unificar los distintos tipos de caracteres que había antiguamente en uno solo y de esta manera simplificar a la hora de que un mismo carácter lo puedas usar en más de una región.

Por ejemplo, puede que, con los sistemas antiguos, un sistema de codificación que te diera el símbolo del euro €, te llevara a otro distinto en otra región del mundo (según su codificación), como por ejemplo el ♥ (es simplemente un ejemplo para que puedas ver claro el problema que llegaba a suponer).

En [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) tienes una lista de los más usados.