# un nombre de caracter universal especifica un caracter no valido con QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy intentando mostrar las teclas unicode para aprender más sobre el tema. El char contiene el unicode del siguiente modo '\u0041'. Es un QString del siguiente "\u0041" que lo convierto a char '\u0041'.Codigo:

```
char myChar = s[0].toLatin1(); // lo convierto en char
```

Pero cuando pongo el código en el case:

```
 switch (myChar){
            // 
            case '\u0001': qDebug() << "aprendiendo";break;
            default:break;
        }
```

Este es el error que me da :
un nombre de carácter universal especifica un carácter no valido

Entonces es imposible mostrar un unicode con un char, que código debo utilizar. Quiero aprender a mostrarlo con switch no con if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utf16 es para 2 bytes es decir 16 bits mientras que char es para 1 byte es decir 8 bits. Entonces cual es la manera más facil para mí
Utilizo wchar_t que es para unicode , es decir un caracter que utiliza unicode entonces lo defino así:

```
wchar_t myChar = s[0].unicode();
```

Entonces lo que hago es lo siguiente, en el switch lo convierto a char para que lo evalue y en case uso el caracter en formato unicode:

```
switch ((char)myChar){
            // Number keys
            case '\u00C1': qDebug() << "0";break;
            default:break;
        }
```

Hay otras maneras más sencillas pero esta funciona igualmente.