# ¿como imprimir caracteres Unicode con printf? ( printf(" \u0305") = ╠à )

Tags: c, unicode

He leído acerca de UTF-8 y de Unicode, en [¿que significan estos caracteres?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27102/que-significan-los-caracteres-del-tipo-u0/27320#27320)

Sin embargo tengo un codigo en C que cuando hago:

```
printf("   \u0305");
```

obtengo como resultado = `╠à`

¿porqué? y también importante ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?. Gracias

Comment: Y con `wprintf()`, ¿Qué te marca?

Comment: No habia probado `wprintf`. ahora que lo marco con la libreria `wchar.h` y haciendo `wprintf(L"\u0305")` obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: Entonces agregale el `setlocale` a ver que tal.

Comment: Posible duplicado: [`wchar_t` no imprime letras con tildes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/69803/4499)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, no es necesario que uses printf. La secuencia de escape `\u` es interpretada por el compilador C, (no por la librería estandar, al momento de llamar `printf`), al igual que la secuencia `\n` por ejemplo. Daría lo mismo que imprimas `puts("   \u0305")`.

Ahora bien, cuando escribimos `\u0305` le estamos diciendo al compilador C : aloca en esta cadena de caracters un byte para el espacio inicial y despues el codepoint Unicode número 0x[0305](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/305/index.htm) (hexadecimal). Cómo se almacena esto en el string (en tiempo de compilación, al convertir de código fuente a ejecutable u objeto binario), depende de los seteos (`locale`) de tu sistema. Si estás usando UTF-8, serán -en este caso- dos bytes.

Al momento de imprimirlo (en consola o a un archivo) esos bytes se emitirán tal cual. Para que tus ojos lo vean como el caracter que Unicode dice ser, la consola o el visor de archivos deben estar de acuerdo con el compilador.

En total, deben cumplirse varias condiciones:

- El compilador C debe entender la secuencia `\u`  (sucede con casi todos)
- El locale que encuentre el compilador debe ser alguna variante Unicode (normalmente UTF-8)
- Si lo ves en consola: tu consola debe estar seteada en algún modo apto para Unicode (normalmente UTF-8)
- La tipografía de tu consola debe incluir el glifo para ese carácter particular (Unicode tiene mas de 120000 caracteres, uno no puede esperar ver correctamente todos)

Lo que adivino que está pasando en tu caso es:

- Tu compilador está usando UTF-8 . El caracter número 0305 se codifican como la secuencia de bytes `0xCC` `0x85`
- Tu consola no está usando UTF.8, sino un modo ASCII extendido (un byte por caracter) - y uno bastante anticuado, el [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), el que se usaba en [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). Si buscas en la tabla los (dos!) caracteres 0xCC y 0x85 verás que corresponden a lo que estás viendo.

Entonces, lo que debes hacer es setear tu consola/terminal para que, al momento de interpretar los bytes como texto (algo que toda consola hace, y es importante que de vez en cuando tomemos conciencia de eso) use UTF-8.

Más en general, un programador no debe depender de la consola. Para estar seguro de lo que está imprimiendo tu programa, redirige la salida a un archivo y mira el resultado con un visor hexadecimal.

Comment: Ok, Muchas gracias por la repuesta. he seteado la consola para que trabaje en unicode, a traves de `chcp 65001` pero no logro hacer que el programa compile en unicode

Comment: Si mi explicación fue correcta, entonce ya estabas compilando en unicode, tu unico problema era la consola. No entiendo cual es tu nuevo problema. Hiciste lo que te dije de dirigir la salida a un archivo y asegurarte del contenido?